# Matching Uppercase words

Tags: regex, perl

How to match following words easily using regular expression in Perl ?

**Example**

AFSAS245F gdsgasdg (agadsg,asdgasdg, .ASFH(gasdgsadg) )

ASG23XLG  hasdg (dagad, SgAdsga, .FG(haha))

**Expected output** :-
[Match First uppercase words only]

AFSAS245F

ASG23XLG

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having? Please show us your code.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to find strings that consist of - whitespace followed by one or more uppercase letters or numbers followed by whitespace. I'd start by trying to translate that into a regex.

Comment: @Dave Cross I have two issues..First i have to grep only the lines which having Uppercase words at the beginning with a whitespace and in that line '(' has to be present.I want to match these types of line.Uppercase words

Comment: @Dave Cross Second,In that matched line i need to get only the first uppercase  words without any whitespaces..How to achieve the solution?

Comment: @DaveCross I have tried with regular expressions like /[A-Z]\s+/..But,it is not working properly..So,I need a proper solution for the two constraints.

Comment: Try this regex: `^[A-Z0-9]+` Working example: https://regex101.com/r/KsUnzM/1/

Comment: @RahulSharma "Expected output :- [Match First uppercase words only]", so if the input starts with anything else than a number or uppercase letter, this regex won't fulfill krrish's requirement

Comment: @Chris, you mean white space or any other special character? For white space, you can do this `^[\sA-Z0-9]+`. You can add more character classes as per your requirement.

Comment: @RahulSharma Do you have any idea about  my first constraint?.. Match the line which having Uppercase word with a whitespace and in that same line should have '(' anywhere in that line..

Comment: @krrish: My point was really that we're not here to give you answers when you can't show much effort yourself. If this is coursework, then you should go back to your lecturer to ask for more instruction. If it is for work then you should ask your colleagues for help.

Comment: Example : AFSAS245F gdsgasdg (agadsg, [correct output]..because having uppercase words at beginning and having '(' character in that line..

Comment: @krrish: *and in that line '(' has to be present* You haven't mentioned this requirement in your question at all. Programming is about precision and accuracy. Unless you share all of the requirements, no-one will give you a complete answer.

Comment: @krrish: If you want help, your best bet is to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55063862/edit) to add a complete runnable example, with input data and showing us the expected output. And explain **all** of the rules that you are following to create the output. And do it soon. Your question is in danger of being closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  print "$1\n" if /^([A-Z0-9]+)\s+.*\(/;
```

this prints only the first word (followed by a newline char) if the line starts with that word followed by space(s) and a ( somewhere after.

Answer (score 0):

*This isn't an answer to your question (so I'm fine with it being deleted if people think that's appropriate), but I thought it would be useful to show you how this question should have been asked.*

I'm trying to filter data out of the input below. I'm trying to extract the first whitespace-delimited word that consists solely of uppercase letters and digits. In addition, I need to ignore lines that don't contain `(`.

Here's a test program.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

while (<DATA>) {
  # This is where I need help. This regex obviously doesn't work
  print if /[A-Z]\s+/;
}

__DATA__
AFSAS245F gdsgasdg (agadsg,asdgasdg, .ASFH(gasdgsadg) )
ASG23XLG hasdg (dagad, SgAdsga, .FG(haha))
```

The output I'm expecting from this is:

```
AFSAS245F
ASG23XLG
```

*(It's also worth pointing out that this isn't particularly good test data. You should include a line that doesn't have `(` in it - as that tests an important part of the requirements.)*